# Laravel Migration is working but cannot access with Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-5, eloquent

I have some issues with my Laravel.

Migrations work fine but when I try to insert or access data with Eloquent I have an error:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

**.env** file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myddb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

**database.php** file:

```
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' =>'127.0.0.1',
'port' => '3306',
'database' =>'myddb',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'password',
```

I use **Docker**.

Comment: when you're using docker check the hostname. DB should be in another container, so enter the container/service name as db host, not localhost

Comment: Show us your relevant docker-compose.yml snippet (the one where you define your mysql)

Comment: I 'm pretty new to Docker so here my ddb part in my docker-compose.yml

`mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: '5.7-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes:
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}`

I use phpmyadmin too (and it works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your docker-compose.yml shows the folowing:

```
version: '2'
services:

  thedatabase:
    build:...

  web:
    ...
```

Your `.env` file should read:

```
DB_HOST=thedatabase
```

That way your docker images will communicate. And always when you have to run any artisan command, simply enter to image and run the command. For example:

```
my@computer $ docker-compose exec web bash
docker:web $ php artisan migrate
```

Or command a image to run a command like so:

```
docker-compose exec web php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly! Wow i didn't know it works like that with Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Your DB should be your docker container so it should look something like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database <== needs to be named after your database container name
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myddb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```